# How to create a bash equivalent of a csh alias that sets a variable

Tags: bash, alias, csh

I've been bashing my head trying to create the bash equivalent of a csh alias.  The fairly simple alias in csh is:

```
alias gfiles='files="\`grep -l \\!*\`"; echo $files'
```

In bash an alias won't work because of the parameter substitution and a function won't work because it needs to set a variable in the parent shell.
This alias allows you to vi or ls or more the matching files.  The echo is not absolutely necessary but I've found it useful.
Any idea how to do the equivalent in bash?

Comment: Huh? Functions absolutely can set variables in the callers; they don't run in subprocesses unless you do something that forces that.

Comment: that said, using a **scalar variable** (a single string) to store a **list** of filenames (each of which is a string itself) is exceedingly bad practice. What happens if it needs to store names with spaces? Appropriate practice is to use an array.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are not run in a child, so they definitely can set environment variables.

```
gfiles() {
  files="$(grep -l "$@")"
  echo "$files"
}
```

(I'm not sure what your alias does; I suspect it has a typo.)

Comment: The alias is an attempt to rewrite a csh alias into a bash one. Thus, cleaned up, the target `grep` inside the function should be `grep -l $*` as the `\\!*` is csh syntax for the csh alias's arguments

Comment: @CraigEstey: Ah, Ok. In that case, the correct substitution is "$@", which doesn't re-wordsplit the arguments. Thanks. Edited the answer.